# Swapping Two Divs with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, swap, element

I have a bunch of floating divs in a box arranged as follows:

[image: 9 divs of boxes floating in aother div]

The HTML is simple, and looks something like this:

```
<div class="square">0</div>
<div class="square">1</div>
<div class="square">2</div>
```

Each box has events and other properties on it, and I am having trouble swapping two divs with each other (e.g. 7 and 8, or 1 and 4, etc). I have tried an approach like this (where id1 and id2 are the indexes of the two divs being swapped):

```
var temp = box.children[id1];
area.children[id1] = box.children[id2];
area.children[id2] = temp;
```

But this yields no results. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: No, I cannot! Is there a way to do this in plain Javascript?

Comment: @PraveenKumar he wants to swap any two indexes, not just the adjacent ones. Is the linked answer doing the same?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Doesn't it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I saw the answers, they are only swapping adjacent indexes. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @gurvinder372 I am not sure, but looks like the dupe is not the right one. So I reopened it.